# Child born in the UK to parents on health care visa ( Tier 2)

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa, children, health-care

I have a 4 months old baby who was born in UK. I am on health care visa/Tier 2 and exempted from paying IHS. My child is booked for an investigation(scan). Please do I need a visa or brp for the child before she can access the care or do I need to pay for the nhs services. I am worried.

Comment: AFAIK children require a dependent visa even in case they were born in the United Kingdom, as residency is not granted automatically. If approved, the healthcare surcharge [will not apply](https://www.gov.uk/health-care-worker-visa)